# Multiple concurrent database connections in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-connection

I have a rails application used by several customers. Each client access trough a domain, but all the domains work with the same rails app:

```
my-client-1.mycompany.com
my-client-2.mycompany.com
my-client-n.mycompany.com
```

The application works with multiple databases, one database per client. All of the databases have the same structure, they are identical. I have one configuration per database in database.yml:

```
my-client-1:
 adapter:
 username:

my-client-2:
 adapter:
 username:

...
```

I need to indicate to the app that based on the domain used by one user, it must change the database corresponding. For example if the user enters through my-client-2.mycompany.com then the database to use must be my-client2.

I have done that by including in my application_controller.rb this code:

```
before_filter :set_db_connection

  def set_db_connection
     d = request.host.split('.')
     current_domain = d[0]
     ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection current_domain
  end
```

Now I have the next two questions:

1. ¿Is it the right way to solve this problem?
2. ¿What happens if one user is processing something and it takes 60 seconds, and in that moment another user enters through other domain and change the connection because of the code above. Does it affect the first user buy changing his connection and at some point the process that takes 60 secs will read or write to the wrong database?

thanks